# Wordpress SQL Select Error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm working on a plugin on WordPress to help me get tracks on my scheduling and task. I know that there are many plugins that do that stuff. But I'm doing it to learn how to create a plugin on WordPress.

I'm executing this SQL instruction `Select * From wp_jrmr_calendar Where fecha_inicio between '2016-03-01' and '2016-5-01'` on the database. I have 5 rows that match. I execute directly the SQL instruction on the database and it returns the results:

```html
    <table name="wp_jrmr_calendar">
        <!-- Tabla wp_jrmr_calendar -->
        <tr name="wp_jrmr_calendar">
            <td name="id">1</td>
            <td name="fecha_inicio">2016-03-30</td>
            <td name="hora">00:20:16</td>
            <td name="duracion">1983</td>
            <td name="titulo">2016-03-30</td>
            <td name="descripcion">2016-03-30</td>
            <td name="todo_el_dia">N</td>
            <td name="tipo_evento">GENERAL</td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="wp_jrmr_calendar">
            <td name="id">2</td>
            <td name="fecha_inicio">2016-03-30</td>
            <td name="hora">08:00:00</td>
            <td name="duracion">0.5</td>
            <td name="titulo">dddd</td>
            <td name="descripcion"></td>
            <td name="todo_el_dia">N</td>
            <td name="tipo_evento">GENERAL</td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="wp_jrmr_calendar">
            <td name="id">3</td>
            <td name="fecha_inicio">2016-03-30</td>
            <td name="hora">08:00:00</td>
            <td name="duracion">0.5</td>
            <td name="titulo">dddd</td>
            <td name="descripcion"></td>
            <td name="todo_el_dia">N</td>
            <td name="tipo_evento">GENERAL</td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="wp_jrmr_calendar">
            <td name="id">4</td>
            <td name="fecha_inicio">2016-03-31</td>
            <td name="hora">00:00:00</td>
            <td name="duracion">0.5</td>
            <td name="titulo">Otra Entrada nueva</td>
            <td name="descripcion"></td>
            <td name="todo_el_dia">Y</td>
            <td name="tipo_evento">GENERAL</td>
        </tr>
        <tr name="wp_jrmr_calendar">
            <td name="id">5</td>
            <td name="fecha_inicio">2016-04-04</td>
            <td name="hora">23:30:00</td>
            <td name="duracion">1.5</td>
            <td name="titulo">Recoger Mónica en Aeropuerto</td>
            <td name="descripcion"></td>
            <td name="todo_el_dia">N</td>
            <td name="tipo_evento">GENERAL</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

But the WordPress is giving me back this error:

> Error  de la base de datos de WordPress para la consulta Select * From wp_jrmr_calendar Where fecha_inicio between '2016-03-01' and '2016-05-01' realizada por do_action('wp_ajax_search_calendar'), call_user_func_array, HostelApp\Calendar\CalendarManager->search_calendar, HostelApp\Calendar\Calendar->getCalendar.

I know that the database query is correct, but I don't know what else look for to find the error.

The query is trigged by this function on Javascript

```js
function search_events (year, month){
   
  jQuery.ajax({ 
   type: 'post',
   url: js_object.ajaxurl,
   async: false,
   data:{
           'action': 'search_calendar',
           'year': year,
           'month': month
   }, 
   success: function(response){
        jQuery('section[role="error_message"]').empty();
        if (response.success){
         listado_eventos = response.data;
        }
        else {
         jQuery('section[role="error_message"]').append(
           '<article class="alert alert-danger">'+response.data+'</article>');
        }
       }
  });
  return listado_eventos;
 }
```

And executed by these two functions on php

```js
 public function search_calendar(){
  $year = $this->param('year');
  $moth = $this->param('month');
  
  if ((!$year) || (!$moth)){
   wp_send_json_error('Los campos de mes y año son obligatorios ');
  }
  else{
   $mothnext = $moth+1;
   if ($moth < 10) $moth = "0".$moth;
   if ($mothnext < 10) $mothnext = "0".$mothnext;
   $where = "fecha_inicio between '".$year."-".$moth."-01' and '".$year."-".$mothnext."-01'";
   $items = $this->calendar->getCalendar($where);
   if (count($this->calendar->getErrorMsgs())>0){
    wp_send_json_error($this->calendar->getErrorMsgsAndClean());
   }
   else wp_send_json_success($items);
  }
 }
```

```js
public function getCalendar($where){
        global $wpdb
  $sql = 'Select * From '.$wpdb->prefix.$this->tablename;
  if (!empty($where))
   $sql =$sql." Where ".$where;
  $items = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
  if (!empty($wpdb->print_error()))
   $this->setErrorMsg('Search Operation error: '.$wpdb->print_error());
  
  return $items;
 }
```

But the really strange think is the query return only the last row of the query.

Comment: You should post the code instead of some html that does not seem related to your problem.

Comment: Hello, I'm update the post with the php and javascript code that trigge the sql query.

Comment: Hello, I found a work around. Changin the where clausule from fecha_inicio between '2016-03-01' and '2016-04-01' to fecha_inicio >= '2016-03-01' and fecha_inicio < '2016-04-01' and now works. I'm still getting the error message, but i'm retrieving the data from database. What is strange is that I get that message only when I'm calling the database in functions called through ajax. But al least now is working.

Answer (score 0):

**global $wpdb** missing semicolon(;)

```
public function getCalendar($where){
        global $wpdb;
        $sql = 'Select * From '.$wpdb->prefix.$this->tablename;
        if (!empty($where))
            $sql =$sql." Where ".$where;
        $items = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
        if (!empty($wpdb->print_error()))
            $this->setErrorMsg('Search Operation error: '.$wpdb->print_error());

        return $items;
    }
```

**Case 2 :** Might be your condition is match.So,It gives you single column.

Comment: thanks for answering. but the semicolon error it's my bad, I made this mistake when I translate the function on the post.